# Unable to Download Blender 2.75a

Tags: installation

I am attempting to download Blender 2.75a on a Windows 7 platform (64).  I keep getting a download error after the download appears complete which says:

“Internet Explorer has stopped working”

My webpage then closes out.
Is this a security setting problem or some other issue with my desktop?

Comment: Try looking in your Download folder. The file may be there. Otherwise, try downloading with a different browser.

Comment: Does this happen for any other downloads or just this one?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firefox and download the program. Re-download the program and see if it works, and if not there is something wrong with your registries.